# Copy Video from WhatsApp package directory to another directory in Android Q and above

Tags: android, whatsapp, scoped-storage

In anroid Q whatsapp data is stored in its package directory. I have got the package permission from user using Document. The problem i am facing is how to copy video from whatsapp package directory to another directory like Movies, Videos etc.

Comment: Which Document did you use? And what is a package permission? And where exactly is that package directory?

Comment: @blacksapps Document tree. Taking permission from user to access data of scoped directory.  Package directory is in Android folder

Comment: Quite vague all. No serious response too.